# Java: creating an array inside of an object class?

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop

I'm attempting to save an `x` amount of integers inside of an object class. I'm trying it via an `array` but am not sure if this is possible and as of now eclipse is giving me two errors. One asking me to insert an Assignment operator inside of my `Gerbil()` class and another saying that I can't make a `static` reference to to the non-static field `food`. The result I'm looking for is `food 1 = first input; food 2 = second input;` until it hits the total amount of food.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gerbil {

public String name;
public String id;
public String bite;
public String escape;
public int[] food;

public Gerbil() {
  this.name = "";
  this.id = "";
  this.bite = "";
  this.escape = "";
  this.food[]; // I'm not sure what I should put here. This is where I want to store
}              // the different integers I get from the for loop based on the
               // total number of foods entered. So if totalFoods is 3, there should
               // be 3 integers saved inside of the object class based on what's typed
               // inside of the for-loop. Or if totalFoods = 5, then 5 integers.

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many foods?");
int totalFood = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("How many gerbils in the lab?");

int numberOfGerbils = keyboard.nextInt();
Gerbil[] GerbilArray = new Gerbil[numberOfGerbils];

for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfGerbils; i++){
    GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil();

    System.out.print("Lab ID:");
    String id = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Gerbil Nickname:");
    String name = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Bite?");
    String bite = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Escapes?");
    String city = keyboard.nextLine();

    for (int j = 0; j < totalFood; j++) {
        System.out.println("How many of food " + (j+1) + "do you eat?:");
        food[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

}
}
}
```

Comment: `food[j] = keyboard.nextInt();`. Whose food is this?

Comment: food[j] is gerbilArray[i]'s food. I want it to run for j = total number of food. But I want it to do be able to save each specific food, and do this for each gerbil. So gerbilArray[i+1] will be asked the same, and can save different numbers for each food food[j].

Comment: It's because of the i <= numberOfGerbils. It should just be i < numberOfGerbils

Comment: Just because you found an answer, does not mean you should clear out the question and tell us that it must be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the number of food in the Gerbil constructor :

```
public Gerbil(int totalFood) {
   this.name = "";
   this.id = "";
   this.bite = "";
   this.escape = "";
   this.food[] = new int[totalFood]; 
}
```

And then in the loop will look like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfGerbils; i++){
GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil(totalOfFood);

System.out.print("Lab ID:");
String id = keyboard.next();

System.out.print("Gerbil Nickname:");
String name = keyboard.next();

System.out.print("Bite?");
String bite = keyboard.next();

System.out.print("Escapes?");
String city = keyboard.nextLine();

for (int j = 0; j < totalFood; j++) {
    System.out.println("How many of food " + (j+1) + "do you eat?:");
    GerbilArray[i].food[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

}

Or something like that should do it.

Comment: Then you should vote for my answer. This is the whole concept of this website.